# java code to typescript in nodejs conversion

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, generics

I want to convert this java classes to nodejs  but have problem with concept of understanding the generics.
**I will be appreciated to describe the part generics and help me to convert to nodejs typescript**

EditorState class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EditorState{
private final String content;

public EditorState(String content){
    this.content = content;
}
public String getContent(){
    return content;
}
}
```

History class:

```
  public class History {

  private List<EditorState> states = new ArrayList<>();
  
  public void push(EditorState state){
     state.add(state);
  }  
  }
```

Comment: You are going to have a **really *bad*** time. Posted code is Java. Java is unrelated to JavaScript. Typescript is related to JavaScript.

Comment: i know i want to convert this classes to typescript.

Comment: And that is why you are going to have a **bad** time. Java is totally unrelated to typescript and javascript.

Comment: I know what you mean it's just sample code about some design pattern that I want to understand in typescript in nodejs not a project.

Comment: [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XrDQgzumEbXiFNec) is a possible TypeScript code.

Comment: @jabba how about using generics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics typings are not native to javascript, and at Runtime are completely ignored. In TypeScript They are a great way of identifying something about an object during development. A generic you probably already know For instance is Array<string>, or string[], which is an array of Strings. Your java code translated in typescript with Generics *Could* look like the following:

```
public class History<T> {
    private states:T[] = new Array// Array of T 
    public push(state:T):void {
        this.states.push(state) // assuming code you gave was a typo
    }
}
public class EditorState {
    private content:string
    constructor(content:string) {
        this.content = content
    }
    public getContent():string {
        return this.content
    }
}

//Usage

let hist:History<EditorState> = new History
let state = new EditorState("Something")
hist.push(state) //this is OK, as T is EditorState, and state is an Instance of EditorState
hist.push("Hello World") //This will raise an Error, as String is not of type EditorState
```

Here T is used as a generic type variable, which we define as EditorState when we create `hist`

Note that Generic Typing are ONLY in development, and are removed from the code that executes at runtime, but during development, will Enforce the typings. As such trying to history.push a String value will error on compilation

For more info on Generics there is some good documentation available: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html